# ORA-00001: unique constraint (ABC.XY_PK) violated Error

Tags: plsql

before inserting in the table i am validating if the ID already exists in table.
It does not exists. Even though it through this error. Is there any possibility that the table does not allow to insert may be permission issue.

I have that insert query in a procedure, is there a possibility that due to procedure permission it doesn't allow.

Comment: The error message refers to a constraint violation. A permissions issue would give a different message. Does it always fail with this error, or only sometimes?

Comment: Show us your complete stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

If you check in the first statement/transaction for existences and you run this SP in parallel it is possible that the second (INSERT) statement/transaction fails. 
In this case you can use a MERGE statement which either inserts the data or updates on existences in one transaction.

Comment: hey, thank you for the solution.. i fixed it,I made a bad mistake.